# a problem with text displaying in HyperLink control

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET 2.0

and I want my hyperlink should display with an image and the Text that i want.

like this

```
<Image>Hyperlink
```

But if I'm setting the `ImageUrl` in `asp:hyperlink` control then it only displaying the image not the text.

How can I do the specified thing.....

Answer (score 5):

If you define both **ImageUrl** and **Text** attributes of the asp:Hyperlink class, the **ImageUrl** takes precedence and you can't use the Hyperlink class as a control container.

To have both text and image in the same link use a HtmlAnchor.
Ex.

```
     <a ID="htmlAnchor" runat="server" href="~/yourpagehere.aspx">
       <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
       <asp:Image ID="imgage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/myimage.png"  />
    </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [ImageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.imageurl.aspx) property, if specified, takes precedence over the link's text. To render both image and text, you need to put an `Image` element inside your hyperlink:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="foo.aspx">
    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="bar.png" />
    (link text)
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: but i craete the HyperLink control dynamically , and if i add image to the link controls, nothing happens and the image is not displayed

Comment: var link = new HyperLink
                               {
                                   
                                   Text = "About Us,
                                   NavigateUrl = SEOHelper.GetCategoryUrl(category)
                               };
                
                var image= new Image {ImageUrl = "~/images/image.png"};
                link.Controls.Add(image);
                phCategories.Controls.Add(link);

Comment: That should work since you don't assign anything to the link's `ImageUrl` property. Can you check that the `<img>` element is actually missing in the page source?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if it will act like the same but, you can make a `asp:Linkbutton` show both image and text.

basicly you give the image as a background to the control via css.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1024015/1391402.aspx

But i can not try it right now so again, i am not really sure how will it act with hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method: You could use an image button. The On click method can be dynamically setup on the back end as well to re-direct to a URL using btnView.Attributes. Just another approach.

```
<ASP:IMAGEBUTTON id="btnView" onclick="btnView_Click"                   runat="server" imageurl="../images/buttons/view.gif"></ASP:IMAGEBUTTON>
```